# How to call main

Tags: c#, call, program-entry-point, restart

I've only been learning C# for a couple days and I was wondering how I would call Main to restart the program when the player says 'yes' during the switch statement (when he is asked to play again)

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Choose a gun to shoot at Toaster... ");
        Console.Write("rocket/sniper/rifle/pistol: ");
        string playersGunChoice = Console.ReadLine();
        Random randomweapondmg = new Random();
        int weapondmg = 0;
        switch (playersGunChoice.ToLower())
   {
        case "rocket":
                Console.WriteLine("You chose a rocket.");
                weapondmg = randomweapondmg.Next(75, 200);
                Console.WriteLine("Your rocket does " + weapondmg + " to Toaster.");
                break;
        case "sniper":
                Console.WriteLine("You chose a sniper.");
                weapondmg = randomweapondmg.Next(50, 150);
                Console.WriteLine("Your sniper does " + weapondmg + " to Toaster.");
                break;  
   }

        int ToasterHealth = 500;
        int ToastersLeftHp = ToasterHealth - weapondmg;
        Console.WriteLine("Toaster has " + ToastersLeftHp + " healthpoints left.");
        if (ToastersLeftHp != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Shoot at Toaster again?");
        Console.Write("yes/no: ");
        string PlayAgain = Console.ReadLine();
            switch(PlayAgain.ToLower())
            {
                case "yes": //I want to call main here somehow
                    break;
                case "no":
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("That wasn't a yes or no.");
                    break;
         }
            if (ToastersLeftHp == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("You killed Toaster!");
            else if (ToastersLeftHp < 100)
                Console.WriteLine("Toaster is almost dead! He has " + ToastersLeftHp + " healthpoints left.");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't. Look at creating smaller methods and learn about loops.

Comment: It is not appropriate to completely re-write your question if you have a new problem.  If you have a new problem, ask a new question.

Comment: That is partially my fault (I assume you can see my comment on his deleted answer, @Servy).

Comment: It seems you changed the code so the recursion is in GameStart() instead of Main().  But the method name wasn't the problem.  The real issue is that you want to use *iteration* to solve this problem, not *recursion*.

Comment: @MillieSmith Yes, I saw it, but I couldn't reply to say that he shouldn't edit the question as the post was already deleted.

Answer (score 4):

You call it the same way you call any other method.  You write the name and pass it the arguments it expects:

```
Main(string[]{});
```

If you don't want the program to continue doing what it was doing after it finishes calling `Main`, you'd want to make sure that it stops executing gracefully after that point.

Having said all of that, making `Main` recursive isn't exactly a solution to that problem that I would advise.  I'd strongly suggest simply applying a loop in your main method that continually performs the logic that you have until you want it to stop, and have each iteration of the loop finish when you either need to restart, or are completely done.

Comment: I would add that the reason to avoid making Main recursive is that if a player chooses "play again" enough times, the program will crash with a stack overflow exception.

Comment: @phoog I'm not sure if it's really all that likely for a player to play again hundreds of times.  Mostly it'd just make debugging/understanding/maintaining the program a pain.  But yes, that problem does exist.

Comment: That is true, of course.  My comment was more of a pedagogical point than a practical one.

Comment: thank you for the advice, I edited my post because now I run into a new problem

Answer (score 0):

As a guideline you should try some online tutorials to help you write proper code.
Try avoiding calling the main method as it is the starting point for your program, instead use a different function or even better a different class to represent the game. this function\class can call it self or add an inner loop that runs until the game is 'done'.
Also consider dividing the code into smaller functions, it would be more maintainable and readable.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'm still researching but getting stuck at random parts (you can see my new post)